# How to set Robots.txt or Apache to allow crawlers only at certain hours?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, robots.txt, iptables

As traffic is distributed unevenly over 24 hours, I would like to disallow crawlers during peek hours and allow them at non-busy hours.

Is there a method to achieve this?

edit:
thanks for all the good advice.

This is another solution we found.

2bits.com has an article on setting IPTables firewall to limit the number of connections from certain IP addresses.

[the article](http://2bits.com/articles/strategies-dealing-resource-wasting-crawlers.html)

the setting of IPTables:

- Using connlimit

In newer Linux kernels, there is a connlimit module for iptables. It can be used like this:

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT

This limits connections from each IP address to no more than 5 simultaneous connections. This sort of "rations" connections, and prevents crawlers from hitting the site simultaneously.
*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't control that in the robots.txt file. It's possible that some crawlers might support something like that, but none of the big ones do (as far as I know).

Dynamically changing the robots.txt file is also a bad idea in a case like this. Most crawlers cache the robots.txt file for a certain time, and continue using it until they refresh the cache. If they cache it at the "right" time, they might crawl normally all day. If they cache it at the "wrong" time, they would stop crawling altogether (and perhaps even remove indexed URLs from their index). For instance, Google generally [caches the robots.txt file for a day](http://code.google.com/web/controlcrawlindex/docs/robots_txt.html), meaning that changes during the course of a day would not be visible to Googlebot.

If crawling is causing too much load on your server, you can sometimes adjust the crawl rate for individual crawlers. For instance, for Googlebot you can do this in [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48620).

Additionally, when crawlers attempt to crawl during times of high load, you can always just serve them a [503 HTTP result code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4). This tells crawlers to check back at some later time (you can also specify a retry-after HTTP header if you know when they should come back). While I'd try to avoid doing this strictly on a time-of-day basis (this can block many other features, such as Sitemaps, contextual ads, or website verification and can slow down crawling in general), in exceptional cases it might make sense to do that. For the long run, I'd strongly recommend only doing this when your server load is really much too high to successfully return content to crawlers.

Comment: The 503 might indeed be the way forward for dynamic sites.

Comment: 429 (Too Many Requests) would be the correct response code, ideally returned with a retry-after header -- despite the fact that Google -unforgivably- treat it the same as a 503, we might hope that better search engines are more standards-compliant.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot determine what time the crawlers do their work, however with `Crawl-delay` you may be able to reduce the frequency in which they request pages.  This can be useful to prevent them from rapidly requesting pages.

For Example:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 5
```

Comment: Nice, +1! Reference here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt#Crawl-delay_directive

Comment: thx, i was aware of that one. Unfortunately there is no directive to regulated the number of crawlers. Last time round, we had 12 crawlers hitting the site at the same time.

Comment: FWIW Google does not support crawl-delay -- there are just too many bogus values specified there that do not make sense. If you want to adjust the crawl rate for Googlebot, you can do that in [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48620) .

Comment: Frustratingly, Google no longer respect this standards-based directive: Googlebot completely ignores any crawl-delay set in robots.txt.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using some robots.txt syntax - the feature [simply isn't there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt).

You *might* be able to influence crawlers  by actually altering the `robots.txt` file depending on the time of day. I expect Google will check the file immediately before crawling, for example. But obviously, there is the huge danger of scaring crawlers away for good that way - the risk of that being probably more problematic than whatever load you get right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make an appointment with a search engine spider.

Comment: it is not as so much planning the spider, it's more allowing them access at that time or not. The spider will always be back..

Answer (score 0):

**First Let It Be Clear:**

> Blockquote

**Dynamically changing the robots.txt** file is also a bad idea in a case like this. Most crawlers cache the robots.txt file for a certain time, and continue using it until they refresh the cache. If they cache it at the "right" time, they might crawl normally all day. If they cache it at the "wrong" time, they would stop crawling altogether (and perhaps even remove indexed URLs from their index). For instance, Google generally caches the robots.txt file for a day, meaning that changes during the course of a day would not be visible to Googlebot. answered Jan 22 '11 at 14:25 John Mueller

I tried doing a chron job renaming the robot.txt file during the week. Like an on / off switch. It working say every Monday at Midnight it rename's the "robot.txt" to "def-robot.txt" which now it is not blocking crawlers. I allow two to three days then I have another schedule chron job to rename it back to "robot.txt" for "def-robot.txt" which now its starts blocking any crawler from accessing my sites. So their is a long way of doing this but the first mentioned is exactly is what is happening to me.

I have had major decrease if not all in my indexed links because the GoogleBot could not verify the link to still be correct because "robot.txt is blocking Google from accessing my site half the week. Simple. Chron job scheduling to change the file to the customizations you want could work some what. Thats the only way I have found to customize robot.txt on a scheduled time bases.

Answer (score 0):

I used cron to modify the apache config file.

You can add an include file within the <directory = ...> directive ( eg. Include bot_block.conf) in httpd.conf that has the filters for the spiders  . I have not tried this in .htaccess .

I used setenvif to set a variable and then deny so you can select IP address or User-agent, etc... to match on.
eg.

SetEnvIf Remote_Addr  ^192.168.53.2$    timed_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent  "badbadbot.com"  timed_bot
Deny from env=timed_bot

Use a cron job to copy the filters into the file at the time when you want to block the spiders and
then restart apache gracefully

Use a cron job to overwrite the file with a blank at the time when you want to allow the spiders and then restart apache gracefully

I've implemented this method and it works.
its not perfect since it won't stop a bot that already has requests pending when the time to block passes. but it should quiet them down after a little while .