# Is my website being attacked/spammed?

Tags: iis-7, server, spam-prevention

My website goes 503 Service Unavailable error several times a day. Sometimes it gives Request Time Limit for specific requests.

My website isn't receiving huge traffic for it to go busy.

The trace error logs shows a lot of error requests sometimes 503 or 500. It wasn't like it a few months ago. No changes were made in the code/settings/design of the website.

I found some logs that trace to +Ahrefsbot and Googlebot web crawler so I suspect it's crawling my website too fast. I can't block them as they come in different ip addresses.

Please help

My website is hosted under networksolutions so I can't perform any modifications or analyze what's going behind my website (server-side)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's crawlers that're causing your problems you could try using a `/robots.txt` file.
You can [learn more about it here](http://www.robotstxt.org/), but to block them completely use this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You can [adjust Google's crawl rate](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en) through Google Webmaster tools.
There's an existing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730376/how-to-set-robots-txt-or-apache-to-allow-crawlers-only-at-certain-hours) that should be of help when dealing with Google's bots.

That said, I honestly doubt it's robots causing spikes in traffic large enough to bump you offline. Try analyzing your logs to see what the actual cause is. Maybe you're using more memory than your host allows.

Comment: Thanks. I have blocked all robots from my site and there was a significant improvement in page loading speed. 

How would I determine if my website is consuming more memory when my website is hosted somewhere else?

Comment: Talk to your host's support. They'll often be willing to help you with that.

Comment: Talking to our host's support is talking to call center guy who doesn't know about server issues all he can do is to reset file permissions and escalate to to their so-called engineering team. My website is hosted under Network Solutions. Really frustrating!

Comment: You should [open a support ticket.](https://www.networksolutions.com/help/current-support-requests.jsp). And while I recommend running your own tests locally first, try [loader.io](https://loader.io/) to simulate traffic load, their free plan allows you to simulate 10,000 clients.